# Extend already existing open source php tool in java

Tags: java, php, open-source

Please tell me, is it possible to extend any PHP based tool in Java programing language.

I am trying some open sourcve tools and found one satisfactory to most of my requirment. But my problem is that, the tool i found is developed in PHP language but i know only java language and there are some business requirment as well. I need to add some more features in this tool. What is the best possioble way to achieve this extension.

Please guide me friends.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without being funny, learning to code PHP might be the best way.

Comment: What is this tool? Maybe its sufficient to delegate a specific task to php. But without knowing the requirement one can't say that.

Comment: @ Jon, Super like, but there cant be any way to accomplish this task, rather then learning PHP like Web services is one of the possiblity.

Comment: @ Janis, its a monitoring tool (Zabbix server) written in PHP. Yes there are lots of monitoring tools in java as well. But I found this is relevant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't wrap or extend PHP code from Java the way you would a Java library, but you might be able to call PHP code on your server and work with the results from your own Java application.  See [How can I execute a PHP script from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655620/how-can-i-execute-a-php-script-from-java)

Barring than that, I agree with the comment above.  It might be easier to either learn PHP or rewrite the parts of the code that you need in Java.

---

After seeing in your comments what PHP tool you're talking about, rewriting in Java doesn't seem like much of an option.  If you're starting a site from scratch (meaning you don't already have a Java application that you want to add this to) then PHP is not that hard to learn.  Other than that, you could look for Java projects that do the same thing as the PHP tool you're looking at now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be useful if you'd tell us what exactly your PHP tool/framework does, maybe even give us a link to it's site, then I'm sure you'll get tons of recommandations for corresponding Java tool/framework that does the same thing. I don't think you need to remake a  PHP tool in Java by hand, really I can't think of PHP libraries that don't also exist for Java as well...

Comment: This should belong to a comment.

Comment: Pls refer this link...http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual