# Run PHP script from Java and capture the output

Tags: java, php

I need to run a PHP script from a Java class and get the output of the script in order to notify the end user of the results. I will use Runtime.getRuntime.exec("php "); in order to execute the PHP script, but how to capture the console output?

Any suggestions?

Comment: for that you require php_cli that is command line php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655620/how-can-i-execute-a-php-script-from-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the process can be found by using [`getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) on the returned `Process` from the `exec` call.